# Using the Twitch API to display offline/online streamers

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitch

I've been trying to get this project to work for several days now and no matter how many tutorials I follow or examples I look at, I always end up insanely stuck with code that doesn't work.

I'm using the Twitch API to display all, online, and offline streamers. I started following [the code here](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/building-a-twitchtv-app-project-8824d61fe7a5) ([his finished project](http://codepen.io/ayoisaiah/pen/MyGjpz?editors=0010)) and apply it to my project...but I'm stuck again. I feel extremely confused.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/un5wdnqn/2/), and here is the JS (it's a mess, I know!):

```
window.onload = function() {
    var streamers = ['freecodecamp', 'syndicate', 'riotgames', 'esl csgo', 'Nightblue3', 'summit1g', 'LIRIK', 'PhantomL0rd', 'imaqtpie', 'captainsparklez', 'sodapoppin', 'goldglove', 'tsm bjergsen', 'Joshdog', 'Tsm dyrus', 'mushisgoshu', 'trick2g', 'comster404', 'brunofin'];
    var status, url, picture, x = 0;

    function updateHTML(section) {
        $(section).append('<div class="row"><div class="image-holder" id="user-image-' + x + '"></div></div><div class="two-thirds column"><span class="status-message">' + status + '</span></div></div></div>');
        if (section == ".online" || section == ".offline") {
            $("#user-image-" + x).css({
                background: picture,
                'background-size': '55px'
            });
        }
        x++;
    }
    
        function showOnline () { //Show only online users
        $(".offline-users, .all-users").removeClass('focus');
        $(".online-users").addClass('focus');
        $(".offline, .unavailable").addClass('hidden');
        $(".online").removeClass('hidden');
    }

    function showOffline () { //Show only offline users
        $(".online-users, .all-users").removeClass('focus');
        $(".offline-users").addClass('focus');
        $(".offline, .unavailable").removeClass('hidden');
        $(".online").addClass('hidden');
    }

    function showAll () { //Show all users
        $(".offline-users, .online-users").removeClass('focus');
        $(".all-users").addClass('focus');
        $(".online, .offline, .unavailable").removeClass('hidden'); 
    }



    //fetch the data for each streamer using ajax requests
    for (var i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++) {
        ajax();
    }

    function ajax() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamers[i] + "?callback=?",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                format: "json"
            },

            success: function(data) {
                fetchData(data);
            },

            error: function() {
                console.log("unable to access json");
            }
        })
    }

    function fetchData(data) {
        if (data.stream === null) {
            url = data._links.channel.substr(38);
            updateOfflineUsers();
        } else if (data.status == 422 || data.status == 404) {
            status = data.message;
            updateHTML(".unavailable");
        } else {
            if (data.stream.channel.logo !== null) {
                picture = 'url("' + data.stream.channel.logo + '")';
            } else {
                picture = 'url("http://seeklogo.com/images/T/twitch-logo-4931D91F85-seeklogo.com.png")';
            }
            url = data._links.channel.substr(38);
            status = "<a href='https://twitch.tv/" + url + "' target='_blank'" + "'>" + data.stream.channel.display_name + "</a>" + " is currently streaming" + data.stream.game;
            updateHTML(".online");
        }
    }

    //another API call for more info on the offline users
    function updateOfflineUsers() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + url,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {format: "json"},
            success: function(json) {
                status = "'<a href='" + json.url + "' target='_blank'" + "'>" + json.display_name + "</a>'" + " is currently offline";
                if (json.logo !== null) {
                    picture = 'url("' + json.logo + '")';
                } else {
                    picture = 'url("http://seeklogo.com/images/T/twitch-logo-4931D91F85-seeklogo.com.png")';
                }
                updateHTML(".offline");
            }
        });
    }


}

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

HMTL:

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8/>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="finaltwitch.css" />


  <title>Twitch Streamers</title>

</head>


<body>
    
    <div class="content">
        
      <div class="row" id="header">
          
    <div class="row"><h1>Twitch Streamers</h1></div>
        <div class="options row">
          <div id="all">
              <button class="btn selector active" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="All"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></button>
          </div>
          <div id="online">
            <button class="btn selector" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Online"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i></button>
          </div>
          <div id="offline">
            <button class="btn selector" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Offline"><i class="fa fa-toggle-off"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        
      <!--<ul id="streamers"></ul>-->
        <section class="online"></section>
        <section class="offline"></section>
        <section class="unavailable"></section>
      
        
      <div class="row" id="footer">
      </div>
        
    </div>
    


  <!-- jQuery & Boostrap files -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="twitch.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help or any direction would be welcome, just anything that would set me on the right path again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, your initial load code seems to work fine in your fiddle once you set the loadtype in the JavaScript options in the fiddle to anything but onLoad.

[image: JavaScript options load type dropdown]

If you need your buttons to work, just attach `click` events to them in your `onload` callback:

```
  $('#all button').on('click', function() {
    showAll();
  });

  $('#online button').on('click', function() {
    showOnline();
  });

  $('#offline button').on('click', function() {
    showOffline();
  });
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/un5wdnqn/4/

Comment: Oh that's interesting; over in my Brackets editor it doesn't work but it does in JSFiddle :/

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Brackets works, unfortunately. Since you're using jQuery, does changing the `window.onload` to `$(document).ready(function() { /* the rest of your function */})` fix it in Brackets? Perhaps it's doing something similar to the default fiddle setup. Here's a fiddle that does this and has the fiddle set to onload: https://jsfiddle.net/un5wdnqn/6/

Comment: Weird. I just installed Brackets and saved your code locally and the Live Preview is working for me. I had to close my existing Chrome windows first so the remote debugging feature could work.

Comment: Hmm, what code do you have in the head tags and script tags? That might be causing my issue.

Comment: Stylesheets in the head, external scripts (jquery, bootstrap) then your script inlined at the end of the body. See: http://pastebin.com/GHH2Qz5U (ignore the extra <p> at the end)

Comment: I added my HTML to the question description, do you see anything that may be causing the issue?

Comment: Nope. It looks fine to me. I even changed my HTML to yours and used the same filenames. Are you seeing any errors in Chrome's developer console?

Comment: Just one: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, and it points to the twitch.js file location

Comment: That's likely the problem. Is the script file in the same folder as your HTML? You may have to specify a path if it isn't.

Comment: That was the issue! I thought all files were in the same folder but turns out the js one wasn't! Thank you so much for helping me :)